# Scheduling in a boolean array c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

this is the question:

Write a program to keep track of a schedule over a period of one 10 minutes and to report scheduling conflicts. To represent the schedule, use an array of bool of size 10; this array knows if any given minute is occupied with a scheduled task or not.You should initialize all of the values in this array to false, indicating that the user has not yet scheduled anything. 
1. declare an array of the right size and type. Initialize it, as indicated. Do this before going on.

A task takes exactly 1 minute, but tasks will be repeated throughout the schedule, as follows. A task will have a first time, and an interval. The first time is an integer that indicates the exact minute the task is to be done for the first time. The interval indicates the number of minutes until the task is repeated. If the interval is 0, the task will not repeat at all (so the task only happens once). To enter this task into our schedule, we'll set the boolean value at all those times to true. 
2.write a function that takes the array, its size, and the first time and interval as inputs, and sets the appropriate array elements to true.

1. Your program should repeatedly prompt the user to enter two integers for first time and interval. If a negative value for either integer is entered, the program should terminate. Otherwise, your program should continue setting the appropriate locations in the schedule array to true (use your function!).
2. The program should also check for conflicts along the way. A conflict occurs if the program tries to schedule a new task at a location in the schedule array that has already been set to true. When this happens, your program should print to the screen that "A CONFLICT HAS OCCURRED AT TIME T", where T is the location in the schedule where the conflict was detected. 
   Hint: detecting conflicts is easier than it sounds. Modify your function!
3. Finally, your program should keep track of the total number of conflicts detected since it started running, and should print out this value right before it terminates.
   Hint: your function might return an integer that indicates how many conflicts were detected while trying to schedule the current task. You have to change the way you use this function, too!

and this is my code and i don't know what's wrong whit is can you please help. thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int schedule (bool arr[], int size, int firstTime, int interval)
{
    int conflict = 0;
    int n = firstTime - 1;
    arr[n] = true;

    do
    {
        arr[n + interval] = true;
        n = n + interval;

        if (arr[n + interval] == arr[n + interval])
        {
            cout << "A conflict has occurred at time " << n + interval << endl;
        }

        conflict = conflict + 1;
    }
    while (arr[n] == true);

    cout << "Total conflicts detected: " << conflict << endl;

    return conflict;
}

int main()
{
    int firstTime, interval;
    bool arr[10];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10)
    {
        arr[i] = false;
        i = i + 1;
    }


    cout << "Please enter a value for firstTime and interval: " << endl;
    cin >> firstTime >> interval;

    while (firstTime >= 0 && interval >= 0)
    {
        schedule(arr, 10, firstTime, interval);
        cout << arr << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please?

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong with your code and you're the one who is compiling it, how do you expect us to know?

Comment: I don't think `cout << arr << endl;` does what you think it does.  You will probably want to write a function to display that array.

Comment: Also, in `schedule()`, can you think of a situation where `arr[n+interval] == arr[n+interval]` could ever be false?

Comment: It appears that what's wrong is you didn't pay attention in class and you think stackoverflow is geek-squad for your homework?

Answer (score 0):

`schedule` has 2 logical errors:

1. you need to check the existing state of the array before you update
   it
2. your loop condition should involve the size of the array so that
   you do not write off the end